# Imprimir datos de Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli, join

Realice el siguiente sql, el cual tiene un inner y un left para buscar los gastos generales e individuales de usuarios datos.

Están en diferentes tablas al hacer el sql hace las consultas pero no agrupo el resultado para mostrarlo en una misma td, teniendo como resultado esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intente con group by pero no une ambos resultados al mismo usuario

```
SELECT relacion,relacionu,descripcion ,nombre,nombred,gasto 
from gasto_g RIGHT JOIN usuarios  ON usuarios.relacionu= gasto_g.relacion   
             LEFT JOIN gastonocmun   ON usuarios.nombre= gastonocmun.nombred 
WHERE  MONTH( create_at) = '11'
```

Datos del usuario
[image: Datos del usuario]

Datos del gasto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los valores son tomados tabla usuarios atributos idusuarios,nombre, relacionu con > relacion de gastos_g (esta se debe mostrar a todos los usuarios) nombre de tabla usuarios se compara con el nombred de la tabla de gastonocmun (este gasto se muesta en se le muestra solo al usuario que lo tenga cargado)

Comment: No veo ninguna agrupacion en tu query. Tampoco se entiende que datos queres mostrar. Muestra los datos que tenes, y los datos que queres que salgan...

Comment: quite la agrupacion o el group by porque no me funciono por eso volvi al codigo original quiero mostar agrupados los datos de tabla gasto_g columna descripcion

Comment: por favor, agrega la salida esperada y los datos que tenes

Comment: en la imagen esta los datos obtenidos, lo que espero es que en el mismo usuario se agrupen los gastos en vez de mostrarlos 2 veces al mismo usuaruio como en la imagen

Comment: no por favor, aclara en tu pregunta que datos tenes, y que datos queres, como texto en la pregunta, no como imagen, porque no se entiende..

Comment: ya coloque los datos de las tablas en la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
SELECT  idusuarios,relacion,relacionu,descripcion ,nombre,nombred,gasto , GROUP_CONCAT(gasto_g.descripcion SEPARATOR '-'  ) AS gastos

 
from gasto_g RIGHT JOIN usuarios  ON usuarios.relacionu= gasto_g.relacion   
             LEFT JOIN gastonocmun   ON usuarios.nombre= gastonocmun.nombred 
WHERE  MONTH( create_at) = '11'  
   GROUP BY idusuarios
```

Comment: Resuelto gracias por su tiempo muchachos

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que estas buscando es la función GROUP_CONCAT (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) que lo que hace es agrupar, en un solo campo de texto, todos los **resultados** de un campo concreto, así solo te sale una tupla pero con datos de **varios registros** para el mismo campo por el que se agrupa.

Tu consulta quedaría algo como esto:

```
SELECT usuarios.nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(gasto_g.descripcion SEPARATOR ", " ) AS gastos
 FROM gasto_g 
RIGHT JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.relacionu = gasto_g.relacion   
 LEFT JOIN gastonocmun ON usuarios.nombre = gastonocmun.nombred 
WHERE MONTH( create_at) = '11' 
GROUP BY usuarios.id
```

y te devolvería algo como :

```
nombre:"Irene" gastos:"gastos admin, aaaaa"
nombre:"Fidel" gastos:"gastos admin, aaaaa"
```

Tendrás que usar tantos GROUP_CONCAT como campos quieras mostrar.

Si te fijas el funcionamiento es similar a otras funciones como SUM() o AVG(), solo que da como resultado una cadena de texto en vez del mismo tipo que el campo usado.

(edito)

A ver si ahora:

```
SELECT usuarios.nombre as usuario, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(gasto_g.descripcion) AS gastos_comunes, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(gastonocmun.descripcion) AS gastos_no_comunes
  FROM usuarios
  LEFT JOIN gastos_g ON gasto_g.relacion = usuarios.relacionu
  LEFT JOIN gastonocmun ON gastonocmun.nombred =  usuarios.nombre
 GROUP BY usuarios.id
```

Con esto deberían salir todos los `usuarios` tengan o no tengan `gastos_g` o `gastonocmun`

No he añadido el`WHERE` a propósito, pues no indicas a que tabla pertenece ni conocemos los datos para asegurar que obtendremos resultados, así que, para no liar, cuanto mas limpia la consulta más fácil analizarla.

Comment: tu query medio me ayudo a entender amigo pero en el select faltaron los demas datos que tomo hice fue este lo pondre como respuesta para que la veas aun da error pero ya casi se logra

Comment: colocada revisala a ver que se te ocurre amigo porfa

Comment: nueva respuesta colocada aun sin resultado

Answer (score 1):

```js
SELECT relacion,relacionu,descripcion ,nombre,nombred,gasto, GROUP_CONCAT(gasto_g.descripcion SEPARATOR ','  ) AS gastos
 FROM gasto_g 
RIGHT JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.relacionu = gasto_g.relacion   
 LEFT JOIN gastonocmun ON usuarios.nombre = gastonocmun.nombred 
WHERE MONTH( create_at) = '11 'GROUP BY nombred
```

Mostrando asi los gastos pero un solo nombre no lo de los demas usuarios
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esos resultado no parecen salir de la consulta, no coinciden las columnas..... si lo generas en php deberías poner el código completo y si es desde un gestor de bases de datos un pantallazo, una explicación tan escueta no ayuda nada.

Comment: Por cierto, edité mi respuesta añadiendo la consulta reformada, prueba y comentanos.

Answer (score 1):

```js
SELECT relacion,relacionu,descripcion ,nombre,nombred,gasto 
       GROUP_CONCAT(gasto_g.descripcion) AS gasto_g1, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(gastonocmun.gasto) AS gastonocmun1
  FROM usuarios
  LEFT JOIN gastos_g ON gasto_g.relacion = usuarios.relacionu
  LEFT JOIN gastonocmun ON gastonocmun.nombred =  usuarios.nombre
```

coloque esta ajustando tu query pero dice mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: no uses la zona de respuestas para estar respondiendo a quien te esta ayudando, dale clic en editar y agrega todo esto ordenandolo en tu pregunta, pues la zona de respuestas solo es para eso, recibir respuestas que te solucionen el problema

Comment: ahí el problema es de php y sigues sin dar información, ni mostrar el código que usas, así resulta difícil (y cansado) ayudarte, deberías esforzarte más por darnos información clara y ordenada, muchas veces con reordenar las ideas (y el código) ya encuentra uno mismo la solución.

Comment: revisa esto para ver como hacer un ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @fly el codigo lo he colocado, y las tablas arriba amigo

Comment: te pondre en mi pregunta como tomo los valores

Comment: informacion colocada al final de la pregunta